# Declining an offer politely using ちょっと and 無理

Tags: politeness

Some girls in the Japanese school I study in are planing to do a Maid Cafe, which my teacher have sent me a message inviting me to take part into saying 「メイド喫茶に参加してみませんか？」. Honestly, I don't think I'm fit for the role, so I thought in a polite way to refusing him. I have thought about many different phrases, and now I think phrases like 「んん、私はそのような事があまり得意じゃないから、それはちょっと…。すみません。」or「んん、私はそのような事があまり得意じゃないから、それはちょっと無理です。すみません。」would be appropriate. I plan sending the first one, but I would like to know if using 無理 is unpolite and which other ways would be better to refuse an offer and recognize the other's efforts. I have seen people using 「気持ちはうれしいけど…」, but it seems way too personal to me.

I know he is my teacher and all, but the first semester has already ended and he won't be my teacher anymore next semester, so I would like to write properly.

Comment: Duplicate of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14087/%e3%81%a1%e3%82%87%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a8-and-or-%e3%82%80%e3%82%8a-how-to-refuse-an-invitation-with-a-specific-reason/14112#14112 ?

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, 無理 is bit too straight and I would avoid using it in a conversation with a teacher. I think your first phrase,

> んん、私はそのような事があまり得意じゃないから、それはちょっと…。すみません。

sounds more polite. Although this phrase is fine in a spoken language, it is bit too vague in a text/email message. I would use 遠慮 instead of 無理 and say something like「誘っていただきありがとうございます。ただ、私はそのような事があまり得意でないので、申し訳ないのですが今回は遠慮させていただきます。」