# Correct use of はちょっと?

Tags: translation

Duolingo is telling me that the correct translation for "I don't really like this wallet" is "このさいふはちょっと".

Is this correct?

If I put that Japanese into an online translator, like Google, it says it means "This life is a little", and I always though ちょっと meant "a little", not "I don't like".

[image]

Comment: Is this a  duplicate? I swear I saw something about omission somewhere... The literal translation is literally "This wallet is a little" and it euphemistically omits. Also please do not rely on Duolingo solely and I am so glad you're on this site

Comment: [Declining an offer politely using ちょっと and 無理](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69213)

Comment: *Google, it says it means "This life is a little"* - I don't know where Google got "life" from, but usually you will get better results if kanji is used. If さいふ is rendered as 財布, then Google translates it correctly as "wallet."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that この財布はちょっと literally means "This wallet is a little...". It's an incomplete sentence.

The reason this is supposed to mean "I don't like this wallet" has to do with the Japanese culture of being polite and not offending people, this includes not publicly expressing dissent or dislike. So, instead of saying out loud この財布は嫌なんだ (or です) "I don't like this wallet", they wanna speak in a more reserved fashion, leading to the euphemism of "Well, this wallet is kinda... (not my thing, you know?)" この財布はちょっと…（やっぱり好きになれないなー）

Other examples include the infamous 行けたら行く(lit. I'd go if I can), but countless people will tell you it means "I won't go." Again, this is due to Japanese people not wanting offend or disappoint others, so you'd have to read between the lines and memorize some common social norm.

But you are right about the literal meaning of the sentence.

Comment: 行けたら行く isn't the same, though. If someone says that, there's still a possibility he/she will go, as in if they arrive you can't really say "I thought you declined." If they say その日はちょっと… it's a definitive "no". Non-direct, but still "no".